# convert a repeating code to method

Tags: c#

In my project, I am adding ComboBox, Text, Link label to my DataGridView `dgvMain`.I have created different methods for different cell templates as shown below: (*The code below is working*)

**gridLnklbl(string headerName)**

```
   DataGridViewLinkColumn col = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
   col.HeaderText = headerName;     //
   col.Name = "col" + headerName;   // same code repeating to all the methods
   dgvMain.Columns.Add(col);        //
```

**gridCmb(string headerName)**

```
   DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
   col.HeaderText = headerName;
   col.Name = "col" + headerName;
   dgvMain.Columns.Add(col);
```

**gridText(string headerName)**

```
   DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
   col.HeaderText = headerName;
   col.Name = "col" + headerName;
   dgvMain.Columns.Add(col);
```

As you can see, except the declaration of objects, the code for every method is repeating. Just curious to know, can the repeating code be converted to single method? I dont know how to do that.. Its not about 3 codes of line, I have written many more lines which can be make common to those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) [**Extension Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) on [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx):

```
public static class ExtensionMethods {

    public static void AddColumn<TCol>(this DataGridView dgv, string headerName) 
        where TCol : DataGridViewColumn, new()
    {
       var col = new TCol {
           HeaderText = headerName,
           Name = "col" + headerName,
       };
       dgv.Columns.Add(col); 
    }
}
```

There is a [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on `TCol` that ensures it is a subclass of `DataGridViewColumn`.

Invoke the *extension method*  as such:

```
dgvMain.AddColumn<DataGridViewLinkColumn>(headerName);
```

Comment: The problem with this is he has different column types, DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, DataGridViewLinkColumn. There needs to be a method accepting the base type DataGridViewColumn

Comment: @mfanto Thanks, I missed that. Updated to make it Generic.

Comment: @Mr_Green I accidentally had a colon before the `where`. I've fixed the example. Remove that and it should be good.  Also updated to use *object initializer* (Thanks, ReSharper for pointing that out!)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I think `dgvMain.AddColumn<DataGridViewLinkColumn>(headerName);` this line should be `AddColumn<DataGridViewLinkColumn>(dgvMain, headerName);`

Comment: @Mr_Green, please don't make any further edits. It is being invoked as an extension method. I've added a static class definition to make this clear, but you should really read the links I've posted so you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

All your column types derive from [DataGridViewColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.aspx), which has the properties HeaderText and Name. You can create a method that takes this base type, and sets the values:

```
public void AddColumnHeader(DataGridViewColumn column, string headerName)
{
    column.HeaderText = headerName;
    column.Name = "col" + headerName;
    dgvMain.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

Usage then becomes

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

AddColumnHeader(col, "Header name");
```

Jonathon Reinhart has a cleaner solution using extension methods, which I'd recommend going with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of those classes share an interface or superclass (and it looks like they probably do), you could write something like:

```
void AddColumns(params ColumnSuperType[] columns) {
    for...
}
```

where "ColumnSuperType" is whatever the relevant parent type or interface is.

Then you can do

```
AddColumns(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(), new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn(), etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

All your column objects are derived from DataGridViewColumn, try something like this:

```
private void yourMethode(DataGridViewColumn col)
{
   col.HeaderText = headerName;     
   col.Name = "col" + headerName;   
   dgvMain.Columns.Add(col);   
}
```